# Custom selection of node in apache in case a node goes down

Tags: apache, load-balancing, sticky, jsessionid

How can i configure apache for load balancing with stickiness so that if 1 node goes down then all the requests for that node will go to a machine which i want it to go.

Ex: 
We have 3 nodes A, B, C. load was distributed evenly based on jsessionid.
C goes down.
All the session with jsessionid having more number of even characters (0, 2, 4, 6, 8) go to machine B and all the session with jssessionid having more number of odd characters (1,3, 5, 7, 9) go to machine A. If both are equal then session should go to A.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to achieve the exact same scenario as i can not plugin any algorithm to pick nodes but i am able to live by naming the nodes and routing request based on node id. Also once any node goes down and when a new request comes for dead node, it will go to any random node from where i will pass the correct node id and all the substituent calls will go to that node. which solves my purpose.